# Intellij cannot resolve symbol even though my class is public

Tags: java, swing

I am very new to this and I am curious on why this isn't working.

I have this class

```java
public class TEST extends JFrame {

    public static GamePanel gamepanel;
    public static InventoryPanel inventorypanel;
    public  static TEST mainWindow;
    private TEST() {
       .....
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        mainWindow = new TEST();
    }
   }
```

Then, I want to access this class from another class that is in a different directory. But, it will not work. It always will say cannot resolve symbol. What am I doing wrong?

I want to be able to access gamepanel, inventorypanel and mainwindow.

(How would I be able to import that package?)

Comment: You mention the error is in code that you don't show us; please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. That being said, if your other class is in a different directory then I can only assume it's in a different package. Did you add the necessary imports?

Comment: @Slaw Alright I edited my message. Yes, it is in a different package, how do I add the necessary imports?

Comment: The same way you import any other class (e.g. `import com.example.TEST;`). Make sure your class is also in a package; you can't import classes from the default package.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you!! That's the problem I was having, it was in the default package. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import classes by adding

```
import fully.qualified.class.name;
```

or the whole package with

```
import package.name.*;
```

The `import` statement should be located between the `package` and the `class` declaration.

IntelliJ should be able to import it automatically when aelecting the class and pressing `Alt`+`Enter`.